# Calculations as per the formula

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I need to do some calculation as per the below formula:

```
B1 = A1 + (1-A1) * B1
```

example:

```
B1 = 0.2 + (1 - 0.2) * 0.4
   = 0.52

C1 = 0.4 + (1 - 0.4) * 0.8
   = 0.904

D1 = 0.8 + (1 - 0.8) * 0.5
   = 0.952
```

Same logic applied for other rows and other columns, there are total 11.

dataframe:

df

```
A        B      C        D
0.2     0.4     0.8     0.5
0.4     0.5     0.6     0.2
0.8     0.1     0.5     0.4
0.3     0.4     0.1     0.8
```

Expected output:

```
A       B       C       D
0.2     0.52    0.904   0.952
0.4     0.7     0.88    0.904
0.8     0.82    0.91    0.946
0.3     0.58    0.622   0.9244
```

I tried it for 1 with the below code:

```
Df <- df[-ncol(df)] + ( 1 – df[-ncol(df)]) * df[-1]
```

I was able to get the column B as per the output, but not working for rest of the column. 
Please help, thanks. BM.

Comment: How are entries in columns `C` and `D` updated? You only give a rule for column `B`.

Comment: You define `B1` but then you name `C` and `D` your new variables (any of them corresponding to the formula you define). Can you be clearer with the explanation?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please provide all the formulas.

Comment: updated the question- hope its clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this recursively as follows:

```
do.call(cbind, Reduce(f = function(A1, B1) A1+(1-A1)*B1, 
                      x = df, 
                      accumulate = TRUE))
```

Explanation:
Since df is a data.frame which is a list of vectors, `Reduce` will take each vector and apply your function. Then `do.call(cbind,...)` combine the results into a data.frame.

Comment: Not worth a separate answer, but you may like `tidyverse` syntax more `require(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    accumulate(~ .x + (1 - .x)*.y) %>% 
    simplify2array`

Comment: @chinsoon12 - will this work for C, D ... So on ... as there are almost 11 columns.